# Android: animating a VectorDrawable causes weird issues on a lg g3 s

Tags: android, svg, android-animation, android-vectordrawable

On the start of my Main activity I'm animating a ImageView which has an sag as a src. when I animate it on my Huawei p9 lite it has no issues, but when I do on my lg g3 s it changes the image before it starts animating.

My Animation:

```
<scale xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:duration="500"
    android:fromXScale="1.00"
    android:fromYScale="1.00"
    android:startOffset="1000"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:toXScale="0.6"
    android:toYScale="0.6" />

<scale xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="800"
    android:fromXScale="1"
    android:fromYScale="1"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:startOffset="1400"
    android:toXScale="1700"
    android:toYScale="1700" />

   <alpha
    android:fromAlpha="1"
    android:toAlpha="0"
    android:startOffset="1500"
    android:duration="100"
/>
</set>
```

My svg:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:viewportWidth="735.6877"
android:viewportHeight="749.1251"
android:width="735.68768dp"
android:height="749.12506dp">
<group
    android:scaleX="1.333333"
    android:scaleY="-1.333333"
    android:translateX="5.522479"
    android:translateY="728.8684">
    <path
        android:pathData="M515.27073 150.27962l-47.28558 0 0 46.39708       47.28558 0zm-153.103 95.56169l-47.29162 0 0 46.39702 47.29162 0zm134.19239 -36.24731l-35.20437 0 0 34.54079 35.20437 0zm-431.122755 113.63458l59.991155 0 0 -58.86011 -59.991155 0zm26.39811 51.90531l35.204485 0 0 -34.54079 -35.204485 0zm-63.42105 9.9943l47.285577 0 0 -46.39408 -47.285577 0zm124.292465 -14.26226l55.47052 0 0 -54.42177 -55.47052 0zm75.12123 -78.77703l53.43568 0 0 52.42839 -53.43568 0zm119.62259 -117.46013l-47.28858 0 0 46.39409 47.28858 0zm20.37578 54.395l42.19834 0 0 -41.39996 -42.19834 0zm52.30556 -18.18351l35.20138 0 0 -34.54073 -35.20138 0zm-156.79788 22.4992l35.20132 0 0 34.54384 -35.20132 0zm-65.05979 -5.07486l47.28851 0 0 46.39708 -47.28851 0zm-55.15071 29.39119l40.36767 0 0 39.60966 -40.36767 0zm300.64657 -15.20367l-59.98799 0 -0.003 58.86011 59.99104 0z"
        android:fillColor="#be5e60" />
    <path
        android:pathData="M75.500002 407.75793C172.25209 556.29803 433.72202 522.51635 463.41592 331.41082l84.20798 0C516.79678 452.75938 403.61145 546.6513 270.39987 546.6513 167.10779 546.6513 78.003918 488.62411 28.214425 407.75793ZM467.98515 119.74576C371.23012 -28.79422 109.76014 4.9874602 80.06612 196.09293l-84.2079789 0C26.688317 74.744423 138.53105 -15.192491 271.74263 -15.192491c103.28909 0 193.73555 54.075124 243.52493 134.938251z"
        android:fillColor="#ffffff" />
</group>
</vector>
```

How it should look:
[huawei p9 lite](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NiiX3.png)

How it looks after starting the animation: 
[lg g3 s](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ke64N.png)

Any help?

Comment: What version of Android are on each device?  Are you using the support library?  Early versions of VectorDrawable had issues parsing some paths. Especially paths with relative path commands (the lower case letters in the `pathData`).  Try converting the paths so that the use absolte path commands (upper case letters).

Comment: I solved this by changing the svg source so i think you're right. Btw huawei p9 lite api 24 (7.0) and lg g3 s api 21 (5.0)